# MySQL не видно запросов в процесс листах

Tags: mysql, pdo, odbc

Подключаюсь к MySQL через ODBC драйвер по юникс сокету, а так же из ядра приложения через PDO, так же по юникс сокету. Последнее время начала сильно тормозить система и явно видно что это бд, но в процессах листах не видно какой именно запрос выполняется долго.

**ODBC подключение**

```
[DB]
Description = MySQL connection to 'DB' database
Driver      = MySQL
Database    = DB
User        = username
Password    = password
Socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Option      = 3
```